# py2neo.database.status.Unauthorized in Neo4j 3.0.3

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I've tried to access from a python program to the Neo4j 3.0 database but the following error is shown:

File "C:\Python27\lib\py2neo\database\http.py", line 157, in get raise Unauthorized(self.uri.string)
py2neo.database.status.Unauthorized: http://localhost:7474/db/data/

There is already a post of the same topic opened, but it's in version 2.2.

My code is:

```
authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "neo4j")
graph_db = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```

Which is exactly the same as in version 2.2, as it is specified in http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html.

I've also tried to do it like this:

```
graph_db = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/", user="neo4j",     password="neo4j")
```

But I get the same result.

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the database through the web interface (http://localhost:7474/browser/), you have to set a new password at the first log in.

Then, this should work:

```
from py2neo
g = Graph('http://localhost:7474/db/data', user='neo4j', password='new_password')
```